# About a mentor who want to supervise postdoc

Tags: postdocs, supervision, mentoring

I have been accepted for a postdoc position. My mentor is a young and according to his list of publications he has not many papers and/or many citations. I would like to know whether this position add any value to my C.V or not? As I suppose, his experience is not much in supervising students, I have some doubts about his support. May you please list the roles of a mentor of a postdoc? 
When I am looking at the other postdocs from other countries, they bold the name of their mentor of their postdoc as a big name in their field. This is why I have some worries.

Comment: I suggest you list your field. In high-energy physics, you will (should) largely act independently of your advisor; in other fields, not so much. From your interest in Lie algebras, I'm guessing math (which is not my area).

Comment: if you don't like the academic standing of the supervisor why did you apply to or accept the position?

Comment: Research-wise, if you've just finished your phd, then your postdoc supervisor will need to act for a while like a phd supervisor, and they should better have some experience. If you can do your own research then it may not be very important who your supervisor is. Career-wise you want to get access to your supervisor's network of contacts and later use their reference to apply for new positions, and if your supervisor is young, they may be lacking in their network and the strength of their name.

Comment: @AlexeyB.This sounds like an answer, why not post it as such?

Comment: @Mark Ok, did that.

Comment: Finding *a* mentor does not exclude that you have *multiple ones*.  As an illustration, it might be "mentor a" offers you insight and exchange how to address a specific scientific problem (for example, if your postdoc now includes methods not addressed during your PhD), and "mentor b" helps you in a different field like "setup and management of an own research group".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My choice would be to list the mentor unless you think the person has been an actual drag on your progress. In a more neutral case, don't think about a moment in time but about how things will go in the future. If the mentor is in the early career stage he/she will probably advance in reputation and, if so, it would be good to be linked to their success. Perhaps they are seen as "promising" if not yet a superstar.

It is easy enough to update your CV in the future, of course, if things change.

Additionally, if you are beginning the postdoc rather than at its end, you probably aren't yet in the job market. This gives you time to evaluate the situation more thoroughly. Perhaps, over the course of the postdoc you and the advisor will advance together. Such could lead to a profitable long-term professional relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Research-wise, if you've just finished your phd, then your postdoc supervisor will need to act for a while like a phd supervisor, and they should better have some experience. If you can do your own research then it may not be very important who your supervisor is. Career-wise, you want to get access to your supervisor's network of contacts and later use their reference to apply for new positions, and if your supervisor is young, they may be lacking in their network and the strength of their name.